# Package not loading/installing

Tags: packages

I am using TeXstudio. When I click compile I am receiving an error message that reads 'File 'enumitem.sty' not found. \usepackage.' I am not sure what has happened because everything worked fine last week. It appears to not be loading the package and I don't know why. I would be very appreciative of any assistance, please.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you find the package file in `....\Miktex 2.9\tex\latex\enumitem`? If yes in admin mode try Update FNDB and start TeXStudio as an admin (right click). Otherwise you have an installation issue or something nonTeX related happened.

Comment: Please try again! Should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I thought I had done something silly that had botched the whole thing up. Very relieved it was just a server issue.